# New reference in page.xml not working in custom module

Tags: magento-1.8

I have created new reference "new reference" in page.xml using this link http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/custom-reference-structural-block/. When i call that reference using

> $this->getChildHtml('newrefernce') in theme pages its working.

When i call this in my own custom module (ie)in Local folder its not rendering that page.

Page.xml

```
> <default translate="label" module="page">
> 
>  <block type="core/text_list" name="newrefernce" as="newrefernce"
> translate="label"></block>
> 
> </default>
```

Need Help.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
<layout>
    <default translate="label" module="page">
        <reference name="root">
            <block type="core/text_list" name="newrefernce" as="newrefernce" translate="label">
                <label>New Reference</label>
            </block>
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

**Note:** In your case, *reference node* with name `root` is missing.

Also you need to add this

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('newrefernce')  ?>
```

to each layout template file such as  *1column.phtml, 2columns-right.phtml, 2columns-left.phtml and 3-2columns.phtml* and so on.

Comment: Xml file for my local module<reference name="root">
         <action method="setTemplate">
                <template>new/new.phtml</template>
            </action>
        </reference>.When i call childhtml in my new.html its not working

Comment: ok, i will check....